# How do you divide using repeated subtraction in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a calculator using functions and I've challenged myself to calculate without using the basic operators (Multiplying using repeated addition) and I got stuck in figuring out how to divide using repeated subtraction.

Here is my code so far:

```
def addition(x,y):
    return x+y

def subtraction(x,y):
    return x-y

def multiplication(x,y):
    repeatadd = 0
    for i in range(y):
        repeatadd = add(repeatadd, x)
    return repeatadd

#def division(x,y):
#   repeatsub = 0
#   for i in range(y):
        

number1 =int(input("Enter number: "))
while number1<0:
    print("Enter a positive number.")
    number1 = int(input("Enter number: "))
    

number2=int(input("Enter number: "))
while number2<0:
    print("Enter a positive number.")
    number2= int(input("Enter number: "))
    
print(" 1. Addition \n 2. Subtraction \n 3. Multiplication \n 4. Division \n 0. Exit")
choice = int(input(" Enter operation: "))
print("")

if choice == 1:
    print("The sum of", number1 , "and" , number2 , "is" , addition(number1,number2))
elif choice == 2:
    print("The difference of", number1, "and" , number2 , "is" , subtraction(number1,number2))
elif choice == 3:
    print("The product of", number1, "and" , number2 , "is", multiplication(number1,number2))
elif choice == 4:
    print("The quotient of", number1, "and" , number2, "is", division(number1,number2), "and the remainder is")
```

It works but I have no idea how to do a division that gives the quotient and remainder using repeated subtraction.

Comment: Can't mark as a duplicate, but here is your answer from another SE site: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186421/how-to-divide-using-addition-or-subtraction. From there the translation to code is pretty straightforward

Answer (score 0):

Complete code with implementation of division

```
def addition(x,y):
    return x+y

def subtraction(x,y):
    return x-y

def multiplication(x,y):
    repeatadd = 0
    for i in range(y):
        repeatadd = addition(repeatadd, x)
    return repeatadd

def division(x,y):
   quotient = 0
   while x > y:
        # repeat subtractions
        x = x - y
        quotient += 1  # update count of subtractions
   return quotient, x
        

number1 =int(input("Enter number: "))
while number1<0:
    print("Enter a positive number.")
    number1 = int(input("Enter number: "))
    

number2=int(input("Enter number: "))
while number2<0:
    print("Enter a positive number.")
    number2= int(input("Enter number: "))
    
print(" 1. Addition \n 2. Subtraction \n 3. Multiplication \n 4. Division \n 0. Exit")
choice = int(input(" Enter operation: "))
print("")

if choice == 1:
    print("The sum of", number1 , "and" , number2 , "is" , addition(number1,number2))
elif choice == 2:
    print("The difference of", number1, "and" , number2 , "is" , subtraction(number1,number2))
elif choice == 3:
    print("The product of", number1, "and" , number2 , "is", multiplication(number1,number2))
elif choice == 4:
    quotient, remainder = division(number1, number2)
    print("The quotient of", number1, "and" , number2, "is", quotient, "and the remainder is", remainder)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might help to follow this long-division method:

```
def division(x, y):
    res = 0

    xLen = bitCount(x)
    yLen = bitCount(y)

    while xLen > yLen:
        res += 1 << (xLen - yLen - 1)
        x -= y << (xLen - yLen - 1)
        xLen = bitCount(x)

    if x >= y:
        return res + 1

    return res

def bitCount(n):
    return len(bin(n)) - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q = 0
n = int(input('divident: '))
divisor = int(input('divisor: '))
while n >= divisor:
  n -= divisor
  q += 1

print(f'Quotient: {q} & remainder {n}')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns the wrong quotient; for instance, when `n=13` and `divisor=10`. You have the right overall approach but need to pay some more attention to detail with respect to the edge cases. Give it another try!

Comment: @Salmonstrikes Thanks . I have corrected it.

Comment: Your code doesn't handle the case where either the divisor or the dividend is a negative integer.